# Two flows side by side on lighting component

Tags: apex, lightning

Is it possible to have two independent flows side by side in a lighting component?

For example

```
   <lightning:flow aura:id="Flow1" />
 <lightning:flow aura:id="Flow2" />
```

[image]

Comment: On top of my head , we had multiple flows on a page, so it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, for the help.